# How to run webdriverio it-statements in a describe-block in parallel, or one after other?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am new to learning WebdriverIO/JavaScript/WebUI Automation. I have one `describe()` function and inside it I have multiple `it()` statements.

I want to run those `it()` statements, in parallel, or in sequence one after the other.

```
const assert = require('assert')
const LoginPage = require('../pages/login.page')

describe('Test suite', () => {

  it('Should display error when password is missing',() => {
    // ...
  })
  it('Should display error when email is missing',() => {
    // ...        
  })
  it('Should display error when email and password are missing',() => {
    // ...
  })
  it('Should display error when email is incorrect',() => {
    // ...
  })
  it('Should display error when password is incorrect',() => {
    // ...            
  })
  it('Should display error when password case is incorrect',() => {
    // ...            
  })
  it('Should login with valid email and password',() => {
    // ...           
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run your `it-statements` in parallel. WebdriverIO only grants you the ability to run different files in parallel, meaning you have to separate your logic in comprehensive test-suites, which can be run via multiple WDIO processes.

For this you have to setup the `maxInstances: 2,` *(or more, depending on your requirements)* inside your `wdio.conf.js` file.

**Example:** Let's consider you have two features: **Login** (`LoginFlows.js`) & **Register** (`RegisterFlows.js`). If you have `maxInstances: 2,`, and you run both features, you will get two separate WDIO sessions running, one for each of your test suites *(two browser sessions will be assigned)*.

You can read more about it **[here](https://webdriver.io/docs/organizingsuites.html)**. As for running them in a sequence, that is the default behaviour.

So, you can only run different files in parallel, considering each file represents one feature test suite. Hope that things are a bit more clear now!